# please help me decode these "receipts" that are at the end of a block

Tags: rewards

The block# in question is 1048576 which is the very last block in cycle 255
When I use RPC chains/main/blocks/1048576 My baker account is showing these 5 in the list:

{
"kind": "freezer",
"category": "deposits",
"delegate": "tz3adcvQaKXTCg12zbninqo3q8ptKKtDFTLv",
"cycle": 250,
"change": "-132672000000"
}

{
"kind": "freezer",
"category": "fees",
"delegate": "tz3adcvQaKXTCg12zbninqo3q8ptKKtDFTLv",
"cycle": 250,
"change": "-2672971"
}

{
"kind": "freezer",
"category": "rewards",
"delegate": "tz3adcvQaKXTCg12zbninqo3q8ptKKtDFTLv",
"cycle": 250,
"change": "-4550583331"
}

{
"kind": "contract",
"contract": "tz3adcvQaKXTCg12zbninqo3q8ptKKtDFTLv",
"change": "137225256302"
}

{
"kind": "freezer",
"category": "fees",
"delegate": "tz3adcvQaKXTCg12zbninqo3q8ptKKtDFTLv",
"cycle": 254,
"change": "-37100"
}

{
"kind": "freezer",
"category": "rewards",
"delegate": "tz3adcvQaKXTCg12zbninqo3q8ptKKtDFTLv",
"cycle": 254,
"change": "-38750000"
}

OK so the first 3 are perfectly understandable - they are the release of the bonds and earnings from cycle 250, that were then frozen for 5 full cycles, and unfrozen at the very end of cycle 255.  But what about 3?  And the 4 & 5 also really confuse me.  It seems I was penalized for something maybe?

Comment: Did you happen to bake this block? Are those your share of the fees and baker rewards  for that block?

Comment: Yes, these are so called seed slashes because you did not broadcast or include a seed nonce you were supposed to publish. See https://tzstats.com/event/29367355 for the event.

Comment: @AlexanderEichhorn - yes those numbers 38.787100  line up exactly to what I calculated as missing in my accounting system.  that is obviously the correct answer.  but how about this...  Exactly 5 cycles after that deduction, my account balance then mysteriously went UP by an extra 30.100851 even though there were no receipts or transactions that would account for this.  (I routinely balance everything to the 0.000001)

Comment: @BoByrd – its hard to say why. If you like you could cross check your accounting against our flow table. This list of events is the most detailed record about what happened on your account and all its sub-accounts (deposits, fees, rewards, balance, delegation) I'm aware of. Example for one cycle: http://api.tzstats.com/tables/flow.csv?address=tz3adcvQaKXTCg12zbninqo3q8ptKKtDFTLv&cycle=260&limit=50000

Comment: @AlexanderEichhorn pretty cool flow table